# AS3 conditional compilation for variables

Tags: actionscript-3, conditional-compilation

I need conditional compilation for AS3 variables.

**Question:**

Is there any way to have if-else conditional compilation at class level, with single compile argument?

**Details:**

This works:

```
CONFIG::DEBUG {
    public var myVar:int = 0;
}
```

but I need if-else block (this fails):

```
CONFIG::DEBUG {
    public var myVar:int = 0;
} else { // ERROR: no if for else...
    private var _myVar:int = 0;
    public function get myVar():int {
        return _myVar;
    }
}
```

I also can't use valid if-else block at class level:

```
if (CONFIG::DEBUG) { //ERROR: can't have if statement at class scope.
   //debug stuff
} else {
   //release stuff
}
```

I could use 2 arguments, but I would like to avoid it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do that without using `else` like this :

```
CONFIG::debug
// for debug purposes

CONFIG::release
// only for release version
```

For more details about that, you can take a look on [using conditional compilation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html), [AS3 Conditional Compilation](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation) and [here](http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_conditional_compilation).

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanks for the answer.

 So I guess.. it's impossible to do with 1 compile argument...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be achieved with something like this:

```
if (CONFIG::DEBUG == true) {
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

Comment: Not at class level.